# Can I do both weight training and BodyPump?

Tags: cardio, strength-training, weights, rest-pause

I was expecting to get a bit more cardio from a [BodyPump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BodyPump) but experience was different. I felt like I have done a full body strength session. Should I go for less weights? And do I need a rest day between the two. Lastly if I am already doing weights, would it be more effective to replace Body pump with a [BodyAttack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BodyAttack)?

Comment: Providing a link or an explanation what 'body pump' or 'body attack' is would probably help future readers of your question, as not everyone has the motivation to google it just to understand what you're asking. Also, what kind of strength training are you doing on the side (exercises, weights, sets, reps, frequency, rest days)? Bonus points for telling us your gender, age, height, weight and whether you're dieting/building/maintaining and your eventual goals.

Comment: From the links provided in the answer below, **body pump** is obviously a weights-based exercise while **body attack** is the cardio equivalent. I'm uncertain why you would expect more cardio from body pump. And if you already have a weight-based program that you think is more effective than **body pump,** I think it makes sense to perform **body attack.**

Comment: I am a 31 year female. height 5 feet,103lb. Yes on a law carb high protein diet ans eating clean. Do weights 3 days per week  isolating muscle groups 4 sets of 8 reps and  3 days of cardio(swimming/running/zumba) New to weight training(about 1 month)

Comment: I appreciate the comprehensive answers I have got.Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future viewers-

[BodyPump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BodyPump): 60 minute program aimed at high repetitions on common weighted exercises

[BodyAttack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BodyAttack): 45-55 minute class focused on cardio exercises and done without weights

Your feeling after the BodyPump session is congruent with the types of exercises; you'd have to drop the weight a significant amount to see the workout shift towards cardio. If you're already doing weights, and enjoy your program, dropping BodyPump for BodyAttack will give you the cardio you're seeking. If you like the BodyPump program more than your lifting program, you could consider dropping your own program and then switching off between BodyPump and BodyAttack.

I'm not sure which "two" you're talking about regarding the rest day. In regards to your own program and BodyPump, it would be best to take a rest day in between, as BodyPump hits most major muscles and almost certainly would have overlap with your weight-training plan. If you switch to BodyAttack, you could lift and then do the program the next day, as BodyAttack does not involve weights, and therefore you won't have much overlap.

Comment: I opted for Body Attack, and it seems a better idea. It gives a nice cardio workout so I am going to stick with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bodypump with low/moderate weight selection doesn't make anything what weight lifting can do for your muscles. Bodypump by default is HIIT oriented activity which builds heart muscle stronger and help you improve endurance (low weight selection + many repetitions).

If you want to be focused on building muscles try proper weights within Bodypump session + supersets beforehand. It works really well for me. I do 6 trainings per week (2 classes a day) which include combination of Bodypump/Bodyattack, Bodycombat/Bodypump, Bodypump/Spinning.

I notice a difference for small muscle groups like biceps to perform combination of supersets with heavy weight create fatigue followed by Bodypump less weight/many repetitions cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing BodyPump for *decades*, since the 90s. I started doing BP when they were playing New Zealand cover music, when they played the Haka.

Yes, you *can* combine BP and lifting (and cardio). In fact, I think BP is a great *intro* to lifting. You'll get a lot of volume and get into decent shape with BP. You'll also get some basic instruction, emphasis on basic. You'll get some basic variety. You will get better muscle tone but you will not gain much mass. If you want mass, you have to lift heavy, what's heavy for you. But before you lift heavy you will first need training volume (lotta reps before lotta weight) and BP will provide that.

BP will get you into the gym knocking out an hour of sets and that's a start. But there's a lot more to learn after you're comfortable.